# How to make the keyboard disappear from a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a screen in my application that only consists of a UITextView. When first entering this screen, the keyboard is not present until you tap to edit.

But if you close the screen, and then come back to it, the keyboard is still visible, presumably remembering its status from before. I want it to be gone when re-entering the view.

Any tips? I've tried the following:

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  NSLog ( @"end editing" );
  [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Looking at the console, it does indeed get called when closing that screen, but it doesn't seem to help - the text view still has the keyboard when i re-enter the screen.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're calling the right method but in the wrong place. You should put the call to [textView resignFirstResponder] in the viewWillDisappear method of your view controller instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i had to make it so that the view that opened this view re-created this view every time it opened it to get the keyboard to not reappear.

Answer (score 1):

Always set your outlets to nil on:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload
{
   self.textViewObject = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't help though. I put a log statement in the viewDidUnload and it isn't getting called. I presume this is because my text view is being created automatically, as i've put it in another nib as a view controller using IB. (make sense?)

Answer (score -1):

try putting the same in

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

function
the code goes like this

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.textViewObject resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You can also specify the same in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

function as well.